# How to track all child processes spawned by a systemctl service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemctl

I have a system service

```
[Unit]
Description=dynsock server
After=network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/dynsock.env
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dynctl.sh $SERVER $COUNT $BASEPORT $AUTH
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/dynsock_onfailure.sh down
Restart=always
Type=forking

[Install]
Alias=dynsock.service
```

`dynctl.sh` will start `$count` child process. I hope when some process dead, systemctl will restart, and exec `ExecStop` . But system will only restart until all child process dead.

Answer (score 1):

`systemctl` can't possibly know the ways `dynctl.sh` is forking so that it could know how many child processes must be alive at a given time. That's why you have to manage the life cycle of the processes, so that when one child process is dead, the service will be restarted.

I suggest using the main process as a `master` for the other ones, so that by using `grep` or `pgrep` it could determine if all children processes are alive, and if not it will give the comand `systemctl restart <your service>`.

Cheers, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C or C++ process that spawns children, then that master process is going to receive the `SIGCHLD` signal whenever one of its children dies.

By default, the `SIGCHLD` is not managed, instead it kills a process. So if you created your own top process and didn't do anything about that signal, it would already work as you're asking.

If you use another language or a shell script, then the `SIGCHLD` is likely managed and now you have to listen for *death signals*. This very much depends on how your master process was developed. Since I see that your service name ends with `.sh`, I would assume that's a shell script and I think it's possible to achieve what you're asking by using the `trap` keyword like so:

```
trap child_died SIGCHLD
child_died() {
   # do necessary to exit main process, I think an exit will work here
   exit 1
}
child1 &
child2 &
...
childN &

while true
do
    sleep 300
done
```

Since systemd is capable of knowing of all your child processes, when one exits, it will kill all the processes still running and restart your entire service.

Note that the script above can be repeated in the children if they themselves create grand children and a similar feature is required at that level too.

**WARNING:** The `.service` file supports the following option:

```
KillMode=process
```

which means that systemd will **NOT** manage your process children. You're not using it, so you are good since the default is to manage the children. On my end, I have services which run an upgrade of my software, that upgrade has to be run by a child process which doesn't get killed so I use this trick. The child can then update the very service running the upgrade process without getting killed midway.